# Overwriting <div id> with a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables

Im developing a prototype mobile web app that mimics a shopping cart. Ive been able to create the shopping cart and add products to the cart. The trouble im having is overwriting the total cost value. Im able to convert the values in order to perform the calculation but im unable to overwrite the value where the total value is stored. Here is the code ive got to far:

```
<div data-role="content">
              <div class="ui-grid-b">
                <div class="ui-block-a">Title</div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">Format</div>
                <div class="ui-block-c">Price</div>
                <div class="ui-block-a"><p id = "myTitle"></p></div>
                <div class="ui-block-b"><p id = "myFormat"></p></div>
                <div class="ui-block-c"><p id = "myPrice"></p></div>
                <div class="ui-block-a"></div>
                <div class="ui-block-b"></div>
                <div class="ui-block-c"><p id="myTotal"></p></div>
               </div>   

            </div>
```

Now i wish to update the value stored in the "myTotal" id. I have a function called addtocart() and here is the code for that:

```
`
var total = 0;
function addtocart() {

var title = game.Title ;
var price = game.Price ;
var format = game.Format ; 
var newParagraph = document.createElement('p');
newParagraph.textContent = title;
var newParagraph2 = document.createElement('p');
newParagraph2.textContent = format;
var newParagraph3 = document.createElement('p');
newParagraph3.textContent = price;

document.getElementById("myTitle").appendChild(newParagraph);
document.getElementById("myFormat").appendChild(newParagraph2);
document.getElementById("myPrice").appendChild(newParagraph3);

price = parseInt(price, 10);
price = total + price;
var newParagraph4 = document.createElement('p');
newParagraph4.textContent = total;

document.getElementById("myTotal").appendChild(newParagraph4);
```

}
`

Now i know the appendChild is for adding text to a document but I can seem to find a solution to overwrite the value with the new value stored in 'total' when a new item is added.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the innerHTML property.  This will set the HTML inside the element to whatever you set, rather than adding a node.

```
var newParagraph4 = "<p>" + total + "</p>";
document.getElementById("myTotal").innerHTML = newParagraph4;
```

This performs less DOM manipulations and is faster than creating the paragraph on the DOM and then adding it.

Answer (score -1):

Change .textContent to innerHTML:

```
var newParagraph4 = document.createElement('p');
newParagraph4.innerHTML = total;
```

Comment: This won't help the fact that appendChild on myTotal will add the paragraph, rather than replacing it.

Comment: Then just - document.getElementById("myTotal").innerHTML = total. Without creating newParagraph4.

Comment: Use - document.getElementById("myTotal").innerHTML = total - to change the value later;

Comment: Again, this will create a text node, not a paragraph as the OP is asking about.

Comment: Tt will create a text node Yes, but in the paragraph node <p id=MyTotal>. Every text is a text node anyway